# backup with tar

Tags: debian, backup, tar, symlink, restore

I have found that I need this command to make a full backup of the Etc folder

```
tar cJPf /srv/dev-disk-by-label-Share/Myfiles/$(date +%F)-$(hostname)-etc-tar.xz /etc/
```

But what command do I need to restore this backup to a new installation?

And what about preserve symlinks? -When I can see it important when you take a backup of letsencrypt under the folder etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 'tar' man page:

> -h, --dereference
>              follow symlinks; archive and dump the files they point to

In order to extract it (and preserve the symlinks), on a Ubuntu system for example, you'd do the following after making sure 'xz-utils' package is installed:

> tar xhf name.tar.xz

where 'name' is your filename created in the first step that you mentioned.

Comment: Should I be in the folder "etc" I would like to restore when I type that command?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use `tar xhf name.tar.xz -C /etc` to put the contents of extracted archive in `/etc`.

Comment: Thanks :) - What does -C mean? :)

Comment: From the man page, `-C dir` changes to the directory provided (in this case `/etc`) before extracting the contents of an archive; and then run the tar command which will extract the contents into present working directory (which is the same directory to which `-C` flag `cd'd` into; /etc in this case).